# removeChild added in an other class

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I've got a little problem.

I'm trying to remove a child called in an other class.

I've called "viseur" in my Engine class like that :

```
private var viseur:Viseur;
viseur = new Viseur(stage);
stage.addChild(viseur);
```

Now, in my Puzzle.as class I'd like to `removeChild(viseur)` when my puzzle is complete.
How do I do to do that ?

I've tried :

```
Engine.viseur.stage.removeChild(viseur);
```

But it is not working... (and either `Engine.viseur.removeChild(viseur)` )

Anyone know how could I do that ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues at play here:

1. The call `Engine.viseur.stage.removeChild(viseur);` does not work because the variable`viseur` is private to the Engine class.  If you wish for it to be accessible to other classes, you need to make it `public`.
2. However, the other issue with this is that the `viseur` variable is not a static variable either.  So accessing it like this, `Engine.viseur.stage.removeChild(viseur);` is still incorrect even if you fix the variable to be `public`.  if you wish to access it via another class, you can either 1) pass a reference of the instance of the `Engine` class to your other class so that it can access the `viseur` variable or 2) make the `viseur` variable a static variable, but remember if you do this, that means you can only ever have one `Viseur` object named `viseur`.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of the class that create the visuer object? Have you tried debugging the application to see if it the return object from the removeChild call reports it is successful?